# How to stop a service without the full name in a batch file?

Tags: services, remote, command-line-arguments, code

I am trying to stop multiple services remotely without using the full name using a wild card in a batch file.  Something like this **service***

Here are a couple example commands I'm using for my need but as you can see I have to explicitly specify the full name of the process and I cannot use wildcards to find matches to run commands to manipulate those process names.

```
taskkill /s server1 /im service2018.EXE
sc.exe \\server1 start service1

taskkill /s server2 /im service2018.exe
sc.exe \\server2 start service2
```

Comment: Batch can't do this. Is using PowerShell a problem?

Comment: Preferably I prefer a batch for automation where the user double clicks on the bat and it run. I am not sure how I would be able to do this in Powershell

Comment: Do you actually intend to *stop the service* (i.e. using `sc stop` or equivalent), or *kill the process*? Those are two different things.

Comment: And, yes, you can launch PowerShell by double-clicking. Either by changing your execution policy so `.ps1` files can be launched directly, or by using a `.bat` file to launch PowerShell with commands. This kind of matching is much easier in PS.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) with the `/FO LIST` options and then pipe that over to a couple [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) commands with the `/I` switch to search the wildcard keyword as desired.

You can run that through a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop using `"DELIMS=: TOKENS=2"` along with the [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) trick to parse out empty spaces to return the matching process name(s) to then kill, etc.

### Batch Script

```
SET SrvName=Server1
SET Wildcard=service

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "DELIMS=: TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('TASKLIST /S %SrvName% /FO LIST ^| FIND /I "Image name:" ^| FIND /I "%Wildcard%"') DO (
    SET var=%%~A
    SET var=!var: =!
    ECHO !var!
    taskkill /s %SrvName% /f /im !var!
)
```

---

### Further Resources

- [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Variable Substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [Tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)
- [Find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [Taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Comment: Please note that within the `FOR /F` loop, you can be assured the `!var!` is the variable that will match the name of the matching wildcard keyword process running on the remote machine returned by the `TASKLIST` command. Test, test, and test some more as usual to ensure it works as needed though.

Comment: @LPChip I left drive a comment but I'm assuming the OP understands which commands to use for the specific need and he can use `sc`, `net stop`, etc. for the specific needs and the issue was with returning the name of the process without using it explicitly using a wildcard keyword which is what I provided solution wise more than anything. I left drive a comment here and on the question above and stated that I'm happy to further assist so if the OP needs further help with more than just the returning of the process name per the wildcard aspect I interpreted from the question, I'll be listening.

Answer (score 0):

I was killing the service because the service name was consistent but to start the service the full name was never the same on the multiple servers.  I figured this command works for me to start a service on a remote computer without the full name:

WMIC/node:server1 service where "name like 'service%%'" call startservice